# How can I Install Visual Studio 2015 with Update 1

Tags: visual-c++, visual-studio-2015, updates

The C++ compiler in Visual Studio 2015 Update 2 is causing problems with building a project I am working on. As a result, I'd like to revert to Update 1 and port the project at a later date. I've tried the following with either the result being I still end up with Update 2 or the environment ends up in a bad state from which I cannot work.

1. Use Add or Remove Programs->Add or Remove Updates.
2. Completely uninstall, run the installer, select only features from Update 1 and deselect Update 2.
3. Acquire and run an old installer for Update 1.
4. Acquire and run an ISO installer for Update 1.
5. Run the Update 1 ISO installer with the /NoWeb flag. (This actually crashes.)

Whatever I do, I cannot seem to get a clean install of Update 1. This largely seems to stem from the fact that the installer, whatever the version pulls its feature feed from the internet.

Option 5 really seemed like it was going to work until it crashed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found a work around to this.

I've successfully installed 2015.1 from the Professional version of the ISO. Formerly I was using the Enterprise version.

If you need some feature of Enterprise that is not present in Professional, I'm not sure what you can do.